# Relating the column data

Tags: sql

I have a table like:

```
Column1 ||  Column2 || Column3
------------------------

A   ||  01  ||  Test1

A   ||  02  ||  Test2

A   ||  03  ||  Test3

B   ||  04  ||  Test4

C   ||  05  ||  Test5

C   ||  06  ||  Test6
```

Note: Column2 is primary key

And the desired output table is like:

```
Related ||  Column1 ||  Column2 ||  Column3
-------------------------------

**  ||  A   ||  01  ||  Test1

**  ||  A   ||  02  ||  Test2

**  ||  A   ||  03  ||  Test3

    ||  B   ||  04  ||  Test4

**  ||  C   ||  05  ||  Test5

**  ||  C   ||  06  ||  Test6
```

Here I am trying to show all the related data of column1 with "**" by creating a new column. I have tried using the query as:

```
SELECT kh.Column4,
CASE WHEN COUNT(c.Column1) > 1 THEN '*' ELSE '' END AS Related 
FROM <TableName> WITH(NOLOCK) 
JOIN <TableName2> kh WITH(NOLOCK) ON (kh.Column4 = c.Column1)
GROUP BY Column4
```

But not getting the desired output. Is there any other way?

Comment: Hard to help when your query doesn't match your sample data.   Going only by your sample data, you need to GROUP BY Column1, not Column4 as you are doing in your query.   And actually, going by Sample data and desired results, you should be doing a correlated subquery and not a GROUP BY at all.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
/*  Setting up the sample data */

    declare @kh table
        (
     Letter nvarchar(1),
     Number int identity(1, 1)
                primary key
                not null,
     Test nvarchar(10)
    )

insert  into @kh
        (Letter)
values  (N'A'),
        (N'A'),
        (N'A'),
        (N'B'),
        (N'C'),
        (N'C')

update  @kh
set     Test = N'Test' + cast(Number as nvarchar)


/* The requested solution using the above sample data */

select  case when h.ColCount > 1 then N'**'
             else N''
        end as Dupes,
        k.Letter,
        k.Number,
        k.Test
from    @kh as k
left join (
           select   kh.Letter,
                    count(1) as ColCount
           from     @kh as kh
           group by kh.Letter
          ) as h
on      k.Letter = h.Letter
```

Answer (score 0):

In your scenario the below code will work. First I took the repeated values in the inner block and left join with the actual table to achieve the result.

```
SELECT 
    CASE WHEN REP.Column1 IS NOT NULL THEN '**' ELSE '' END AS Related,
    TT.Column1, TT.Column2, TT.Column3
FROM TestTable TT 
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT Column1
    FROM TestTable
    GROUP BY Column1
    HAVING COUNT(Column1) > 1
) REP ON REP.Column1 = TT.Column1
```

Working Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ffa8b/5

Comment: Thanks a lot Arul. It was really helpful. It worked fine. As this is an initial requirement, I am still working on it.

Comment: If the above answer is solved your problem, you can accept this answer for your question by click the tick mark below my answer's voting count.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `COUNT() OVER(PARTITION BY)` function in you case statement, without having to Group

```
--Test Data
DECLARE @Test TABLE (
        Letter VARCHAR(1),
        Number VARCHAR(10),
        Test VARCHAR(10)
    )

INSERT  INTO @Test
VALUES  ('A', '01', 'Test1'),
        ('A', '02', 'Test2'),
        ('A', '03', 'Test3'),
        ('B', '04', 'Test4'),
        ('C', '05', 'Test5'),
        ('C', '06', 'Test6')


--Query
SELECT  CASE WHEN COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY Letter) > 1 THEN '**'
                ELSE ''
        END [Related],
        *
FROM    @Test
```